# Is it possible to convert this simple jQuery snippet to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple jQuery snippet (very simple with jQuery) and I want to convert this to javascript which seems to be really hard.

For example, I have no idea what to do with the .each - function.

Hope you can help, give me a hint or solve the problem quickly.

```
 $("#rTab div[id^=tab]").each(function(){
     if( !$.trim( $(this).html() ).length ) {
         id = $(this).attr("id");
     //alert(id);
         $("#rTab li[rel="+id+"]").hide();
     } 
 });

$(".tabContent").hide();
$(".tabContent:first").show(); 

//click MUSS live
$("ul.tabs li").live('click',function() {
$("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
$(".tabContent").hide();
//MUSS rel, weil href mit location.hash in product.php so nicht läuft
var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
$("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
each("#rTab div[id^=tab]",
    function(element){
        if(element.innerHTML.trim().length > 0) {
            id = element.getAttribute("id");
            //alert(id);
            each("#rTab li[rel="+id+"]",
                function(element){
                    element.style.display = 'none';
                }
            );
        } 
    }
)

each("#rTab li[rel="+id+"]",
    function(element){
        element.style.display = 'none';
    )
);
each(".tabContent:first",
function(element){
        element.style.display = 'block';
    )
);

each("ul.tabs li",
    function(element){
        element.addEventListener(
            'click',
            function(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                each("ul.tabs li",
                    function(e){
                        e.setAttribute('class' e.getAttribute('class').replace("active",''));
                    }
                e.target.setAttribute('class' e.getAttribute('class') + "active");

                each(".tabContent",
                    function(element){
                        element.style.display = 'none';
                    )
                );
                var activeTab = e.target.getAttribute("rel"); 

                //$("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
                // I'm not going to write a loop to fade in a element.
            }
        );
    }
);


function each(selector, func){
    var e = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if(e.forEach){
        e.forEach(func);
    }else{
        for(var i = 0, l = e.length; i < l; i++){
            func(e[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

It's more code, yes. The problem is that all those jQuery selectors can return multiple elements, so it's a loop for every selector. Hence the alias to make that slightly shorter.

At least this should give you an idea of how things work in native JS. Please note that the `querySelectorAll` [isn't supported on older browsers](http://caniuse.com/queryselector), and `forEach` is IE 9+.

Also, in the `.style.display = 'none';` and `.style.display = 'block';`, you may want to cache the old display value somehow, since not all elements use `block` as default display setting.

An alternative to

Comment: If this works I'll +1 for awesomeness.

Comment: you are the best. made my day! thank you. i will study your code to work on my skills harder.

Comment: @Jimbo: It'll probably have some bugs here and there, but that's a challenge for the OP, right? ;-)

Comment: I just added some compatibility code for `each` that uses a `for` loop if `forEach` isn't available

Comment: @Cerbrus: i will try your code. if it's not working i will fix the bugy by myself.

Answer (score 3):

For the `$.each()`, you could do a JavaScript `FOR` loop. You need to learn about traversing the DOM. What have you tried?

The easiest way is to just learn how to do DOM traversing and manipulation with the plain DOM api (you would probably call this: normal JavaScript).

This can however be a pain for some things. (which is why libraries like jQuery were invented in the first place).

Googling for "javascript DOM traversing/manipulation" should give plenty of helpful (and less helpful) resources.

The articles on this website are pretty good: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/

Be sure to test this in all browsers, also.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978799/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-jquery-code-to-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899052/convert-from-jquery-to-javascript).